# Start Magnolia too slow

Tags: magnolia

I'm new to Magnolia and am trying to do the first project https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Hello+Magnolia#HelloMagnolia-InstallNode.js
called ''Hello Magnolia'' In section 4.2 **Install and start Magnolia** when type **mgnl start** it shows *Starting Tomcat instance at C:\Users\BorisPc\Desktop\magnolia\apache-tomcat To stop it, enter CTRL+C* but it's running too slow am almost waiting 30 minutes, previous time it opened very fast but now i dont know why i wait so long.
Somebody help ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: 30 minutes is very suspicious, do you have any logs? like for instance reindexing of JCR or similar?

Answer (score 3):

Check your /etc/hosts file

Mine is:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1    localhost   Yourcomputername.local
```

At least that was the case for slow start in my case beacuse it was missing the last entry. Before that it took ~25 minutes for startup and after around 3 minutes.

Comment: thanks as soon as i added the last line it started working

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. The first start of a fresh magnolia instance was very fast but then when I attached my module it could take even 30 minutes.

After some investigation, it turned out that during the startup magnolia was syncing all files in my module due to this config:
magnolia.resources.dir=${magnolia.home}/../../../my-module/src/main/resources

This configuration comes from
\apache-tomcat\webapps\magnoliaAuthor\WEB-INF\config\default\

The problem was that my light module was build based on node hence in the watched directory I had dirs called "node" and "node_modules". Those dirs contain thousands of files and this was slowing it down.

To solve the issue in the mentioned config one has to add
magnolia.resources.filesystem.observation.excludedDirectories=node,node_modules

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you have `JAVA_HOME` defined. This is my case, where `mgnl start` hang indefinitely.

You can try to start Magnolia with the command line

```
<Your demo directory>/apache-tomcat/bin/magnolia-control.sh start
```

This will give you error details which help troubleshooting.